# Closed form expression of the countour integral of Gamma functions combined with a Gaussian hypergeometric function?

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, contour-integration, hypergeometric-function

Is there any way of writing the following contour integral as a closed form expression ?
$$
\int_{-i \infty}^{+i \infty} dp \int_{-i \infty}^{+i \infty} ds \Gamma(d/2 + s + p -1) \Gamma(-\Delta - s - 2p +1)\Gamma(p) \Gamma(s+\Delta) \Gamma(-s) x^s y^p
$$

where $\Delta \in \mathbb{C}$, $d \in \mathbb{N^*}$, and $x$ and $y$ are two complex independent variables.

I managed to write in a closed-form one of the two integrals, using the integral representation of the Gaussian hypergeometric function https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/07/02/ (after a change of variable $s \rightarrow -s$) but then I am still left with

$$
2\pi i \Gamma(\Delta)\int_{-i \infty}^{+i \infty} dp \frac{\Gamma(d/2 + p -1) \Gamma(d/2 - p - \Delta)\Gamma(1 - 2p)}{\Gamma(d/2 - p)} y^p \space _2F_1(\Delta, d/2 + p -1, d/2 - p, 1-x)
$$

which I don't really know how to write in a closed form.

Comment: You have an inverse Mellin transform. Try writing the integrand in terms of the Mellin transform of another function.

Comment: Also, if you can switch the complex integral with the [real integral](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1Regularized/07/01/01/0002/) for the hypergeometric function, you get [this integrand](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-4+e%5E%28-%281%2Ft%5E2+%2B+1%2Ft%29%2Fy%29+π%5E2+t%5E%28-+d+%2B+2+δ%29+y%5E%28-d%2F2+%2B+δ%29+%28t+%2B+x%29%5E%28-1+-+a%29+δ%21) for $0<t$ which may not have a closed form

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash yes I have tried doing that but for now, I have not been able to do so. Concerning switching the complex integral with the real integral, wouldn't that cause some issues with the potential poles one would have to go through to do so ? Or maybe I am unfamiliar with how the conversion is done...